# what do the square brackets mean? in Java

Tags: java, methods, double, brackets

What does it mean when there are square brackets in front of `double`. For example `double[]`?
Is there any special way to use the return function when using them in a method.

For example:

```
public double[] MethodName(){

}
```

What is the type of the return value?

Comment: it's called an `Array`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: It's for arrays.  You need to create an array to return (or return null) for that method.  Ex.  `return new double[10];`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Square brackets `[]` would indicate an array. In your case of code:

`public double[] MethodName(){`
`....`
`}`

You have a public method `MethodName` which returns an array. Double indicates what type the array is, i.e. stores an array of objects of type double.

EDIT: Forgot about answering your return question. But for your line of code, `MethodName` would return an array of type double (which would depend on the implmentation inside the method body). Hope that helps (I'm new to Java too; climbing the SO rep ladder)

Comment: Anything else that needs answering? I want to have that green tick checked :)