# What is the difference between Java List<String> and List<String>[]

Tags: java, list

I am working in Java and would like to know what adding the brackets does. I looked this up and read through the List documentation but couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The second is an [array of lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: `List<String>[]` is an array of string lists. the brackets are a language feature of Java and have nothing directly to do with `List`.

Comment: Oh never mind I'm dumb. It must be an array of Lists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538048/what-do-the-square-brackets-mean-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List<String>` is a `List` of `String`s (i.e. a `List` containing `String` elements).

`List<String>[]` is an array of `List`s of `String`s (i.e. an array whose elements are `List<String>`.

For every type `x`, `x[]` is an array of elements of type `x`.

Comment: Thanks. I realized this immediately after asking the question.

Comment: I'd like to ask how is this used. I can declare the array of lists without a problem, however, I cannot seem to initialize it. I receive an error that I cannot create an array of type generic. If that is the case how can an array of lists be used?

Comment: @AymanElmubark You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java).