# Difference between String[] (with square brackets) and String (without square brackets) in Java

Tags: java, difference, brackets, square

Just starting to learn Java, I found that "**String**" in this function has two square brackets beside:

```
public static void main (String[] parameter){
    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

But this one has not:

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

What is the diference?

Comment: `String[]` is an array of strings.

Comment: Read the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538048/what-do-the-square-brackets-mean-in-java
Please do some research (or read an introductory book) before posting a question here.

Comment: He's asking exactly the same thing as you. "what do the square brackets mean? in Java". Use Google before StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` signifies an array, or a list of many Strings, whilst `String` is just one String.